# Python problem regarding what this code implies

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I had a question regarding a practice problem I am working on. Its a cryptography problem and I want some clarification on a couple of lines of code.

Code:

```
def encrypt(plaintext, shift):
    result = ""
    shift = 26 - shift
    for x in plaintext:
        if (x == " "):
            result += " "
        else:
            if(x.islower()):
                result += chr(97 + ((ord(x) - 97 + shift) % 26))
            else:
                result += chr(65 + ((ord(x) - 65 + shift) % 26))
```

Can someone please explain the last two if and else statements. Specifically what the 97 and 65 is and why they are being used?

I assumed the 97 and 65 are being used to help decrpyt the messages of the file however besides that i am not sure what they are being used for and why specifically 97 and 65.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. Make sure all the indentation is correct.

Comment: This code illustrates why "magic numbers" are a bad idea. In ASCII, 97 is a lower-case 'a', and 65 is an upper-case 'A'.

Comment: Have a look at the [ASCII table](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp#:~:text=The%20ASCII%20Character%20Set&text=ASCII%20is%20a%207%2Dbit,are%20all%20based%20on%20ASCII.) and you will see that 97 e.g. is a lower case `a`. But better use `ord('a')` instead of hardcoding the number. It's used here to shift the character within the range of 0-26 characters so modulo can be used after the shift is applied and then again to shift it back so it's actually an valid lowercase/ uppercase character not some other ASCII value between 0-26 (which is not an upper-/ lowercase letter).

Comment: `ord('a')` is just as hard coded as 97, but slower. `97` (plus a comment)  reasonable here, I think.

Comment: My Caesar cipher example code usually contains `charToIndex` and `indexToChar` methods as the *what* is not apparent from the code at first glance. By the way, the code is somewhat wrong, the shift is usually the key, so encrypt is generally using the shift directly (not `26 - shift`). Of course the input validation is also missing, but I guess that's OK if it is just to practice the Caesar cipher.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and maybe even python. [PEP 20 – The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)  alludes to the "feeling" of good python code. Those lines do not "feel" very Zen-like. That said, to understand the lines, using the previous comments as a guide, rewrite the code breaking it down into variables with meaningful names and comments about the logic until you understand your code.

Comment: `26 - shift` just makes the shifting go in the opposite direction. Not a problem. No need to bloat the execution with interim variables or unneeded function calls. A quick comment is all that is needed. Python is slow for this type of operation. No need to make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

This code rotates characters in an alphabet. Characters in the range a-z and A-Z shift left the given number of steps. If shift is 1 for instance,

```
a --> z
b --> a 
c --> b
d --> c
etc...
```

`islower()` is used to choose between the two alphabet ranges. This rather lame because (1) there are a lot of lower cases letters in unicode outside of the a-z range, and there are even more non-lower characters outside of A-Z.

But, assuming all of the input is in one of these two ranges, the logic for the alphabet a-z is:

- Characters like "a" are really just integers that stand for letters by some encoding convention such as ASCII or Unicode. `ord(x)` converts the character to its integer for further calculations
- `- 97` rebases the character to 0 for the shift / modulo operations.
- `+ shift` does the shifting. Notice there was already a `26 - shift` operation to make things shift left (left for left to right readers, that is).
- `% 26` wraps stuff that flows over the end of the alphabet
- `+ 97` moves it back to the a-z range

Same thing for A-Z.

`97` is the ordinal for `"a"` and `65` is the ordinal for `"A"`. It may be more clear to say `ord(65)` in the equation, but using the hard coded integer is faster (no function call). Comments should make up for it.